# SOAP WebService not loading due to maven dependency issue

Tags: java, maven, soap, osgi, apache-felix

I am working on one of many modules in an OSGi based Java/Spring application.
The case I am dealing with is, on the face of it, rather simple - I need to make use of external jars by including a dependency into my local module maven pom file.

The problem I am facing is that as soon as the module is compiled and run, with the new dependencies sucked in, and hot deployed onto a local multi-module supporting Apache Felix server I see no SOAP web services defined within that particular module getting started.

Confusingly, it appears the same dependency used elsewhere (in a similar component, that is) does not bring about any problems and compiles/runs just fine.

Am I missing something fundamental in the way Maven/OSGi works or is it that there is some sort of a more serious issue at play here?

The images below should further illuminate the problem at hand. 
It must be noted, though, that the following images have been purposefully modified as it has been assumed the kinds of jars added have no bearing on the way the deployment responds (for what it's worth, it is an external library providing hashing algorithms).

**Before adding dependency running localhost:8080/cxf displays**

[image]

[image]

**Rerunning after including the above dependency causes it to not show anymore**

[image]

Any insight would be hugely appreciated!